# Checking multiple input's validity in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, turtle-graphics, valueerror

I wrote a program that draws a convex regular polygon in turtle (given no. of sides and length). I also wanted it to check for invalid inputs, such that it would immediately ask if the user would like to try a different one. Is there a way to check both input's validity in less code, while also accounting for ValueError?

Also, a Terminator error occurs after every successful run. What might be causing it, and is there even a way to fix it when using this import command?

```
from turtle import *
def inp():
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Enter the number of sides of the polygon: "))
        except ValueError:
            y_n = input("Invalid input, type \"y\" if you'd like to try again: ")
            if y_n == "y":
                continue
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
        if n >= 3:
            pass
        else:
            y_n = input("Invalid input, type \"y\" if you'd like to try again: ")
            if y_n == "y":
                inp()
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
        
        try: 
            l = float(input("Enter the length of the side in pixels: "))
        except ValueError:
            y_n = input("Invalid input, type \"y\" if you'd like to try again: ")
            if y_n == "y":
                continue
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
        if l > 0:
            for i in range(1, n + 1):
                forward(l)
                left(360/n)
            exitonclick()
            break
        else:
            y_n = input("Invalid input, type \"y\" if you'd like to try again: ")
            if y_n == "y":
                inp()
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
     
inp()
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficient parameter inputs, here are some steps:

- Start with the value as something invalid
- Using a while loop, ask the user for valid input
- If valid input, exit the loop

In you're code, both parameters have the the same validation check, so you can use a function to check both.

Try this code:

```
from turtle import *

def validnum(nm):
    return str(nm).isdigit() and int(nm) > 0  # integer and greater than zero

def inp():
    n = l = ''  # both invalid
    while not validnum(n):  # loop first entry until valid
        n = input("Enter the number of sides of the polygon or 'q' to quit: ")
        if n == 'q':
            print("Goodbye!")
            exit()
        if not validnum(n):
            print("Invalid entry")
            
    while not validnum(l):  # loop second entry until valid
        l = input("Enter the length of the side in pixels or 'q' to quit: ")
        if l == 'q':
            print("Goodbye!")
            exit()
        if not validnum(l):
            print("Invalid entry")
            
    n, l = int(n), int(l)  # convert entries to integers
            
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        forward(l)
        left(360/n)
    exitonclick()

inp()
```

Since both parameters have the same validation and only differ in the message prompt, you can make your code even more compact by putting the prompts in a list.

```
from turtle import *

def validnum(nm):
    return str(nm).isdigit() and int(nm) > 0  # integer and greater than zero

def inp():
    lstinp = ['','']  # both invalid
    lstmsg = ['Enter the number of sides of the polygon', 'Enter the length of the side in pixels'] # both msgs

    for i in range(len(lstinp)):  # each input value
        while not validnum(lstinp[i]):  # loop until valid entry
            lstinp[i] = input(lstmsg[i] + " or 'q' to quit: ")  # msg 
            if lstinp[i] == 'q':
                print("Goodbye!")
                exit()
            if not validnum(lstinp[i]):
                print("Invalid entry")
                        
    n, l = int(lstinp[0]), int(lstinp[1])  # convert entries to integers
            
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        forward(l)
        left(360/n)
    exitonclick()

inp()
```

I did not receive any errors when running the code.